# How can I make a Lucene-backed search interface more humane?

Tags: search, natural-language

A client has a search engine [(Lucene)](http://lucene.apache.org/) and it is not performing well with users, partly because page metadata is really vague and non-descriptive and also because users -- if I am to beleive the research in front of me -- tend to use *natural language queries*.

Lucene uses boolean logic and is not very good at handling natural language searches.
**q:  How do I improve the search experience if the tool is not up to the job, so to speak?**

All options on the table including changing the engine. Failing that, do you think there is a way to configure lucene?

Comment: "metadata is really rather" - rather what? I think you left out a word here.

Comment: whoops. tx for the headsup

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what your users are searching?

Comment: This is the search engine he referenced by the way: http://lucene.apache.org/

Comment: Also a good read to understand the tech http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene

Comment: @Matt. that reminded me of "I accidentally a whole bottle" ;D

Comment: And no one noticed "How can make Lucene-backed search interface more humane?" That was *not* intentional, BTW. :)

Comment: "Can you tell us a bit more about what your users are searching?" 
It is searching data about qualifications eg vocational, A-level etc. I believe the data sits across different datasources which makes the results even more inconsistent....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What if you take out the part of the search that is natural language by adding a drop down menu in front of the search input that has that starting sentence....

[image: Suggestion for search]

Comment: That's a damn pragmatic answer. +1

Comment: that *is* a damn pragmatic answer +1

Comment: Ever so very pragmatic answer +1

Answer (score 3):

Lucene when configured correctly is incredibly powerful and configuration tweaks may indeed overcome the problems you are seeing.

Like any technology installing a solution is less than half the effort the configuration is most important after this expect to be tweaking the configuration for quite a while to get what is considered the ideal results set for any given term and importantly performance.

In addition of this you need an interface that connects with the audience and allows them to interact with the underlying technology successfully. Take a look at http://twigkit.com/ for examples of successful UI applied to Lucene as the service is designed to easly integrate with your technology selection and others.

Answer (score 2):

I use Lucene on a small Drupal site. You may want to look at how the Search Lucene DidYouMean related module works so you can apply something similar to your own project.
http://drupal.org/project/luceneapi_dym

Comment: Faceted search can be helpful to users as well.

Comment: yep, that's one card on the table...